# how to do performance test for API calls in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

i have API calls i need to do Pt test for those. how can i do that.
Can some one help me on this please.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you have tried and what problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps would look like:

1. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and define number of users, ramp-up, test duration there
2. Add a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for each API call
3. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to each request (or one for all requests, depending on your scenario) and configure it to send the relevant [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). For SOAP requests you might have to provide [SOAPAction](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) header as well
4. Run your test
5. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and analyze results.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information if needed